# Problema con el bucle Do-While en Java

Tags: java, netbeans, while

estoy haciendo un programa en Java sobre un básico juego de números, el programa responde bien a la mayor parte de pruebas pero el problema viene dado en un bucle que tengo al final, y es que tengo que teclear un número (mediante función Scanner) y el programa calculará la lotería y si esta es menor o igual que 3000000, el contador ("Faltante") se restará 1 y regresará al bucle, este bucle siempre se repite mientras el contador no sea 0 y la lotería sea menor o igual a 3M.

Al meter números pequeños (4 o 10 por ejemplo) funciona correctamente repitiendo el bucle y restando el contador hasta que aparece lo de "GAME OVER LOSER" y se acaba. Con algún número en centena o miles también funciona y sale por la salida adecuada diciéndome que he ganado, pero si pongo un número más grande me repite el bucle como si fuese un número pequeño y es algo que no entiendo ya que si el número que da "lotería" pasa de 2147483647 (rango de entero positivo) me tendría que dar error pero no aunque si pongo un número desorbitadamente grande el error si sale. No entiendo por que...

```
        int numm2=0;
        int faltante;
        int loteria=0,puntuacion1=0, puntuacion2, puntuacionf=0;
        int conti;
conti = 3;
        faltante = conti;

        do {
        System.out.print("Introduzca el numero que se va echar a la aventura: ");
        numm2=newsc.nextInt(); 
        loteria=200000*numm2+1000+1000;    //Calculo de loteria

            if (loteria<=3000000) {
                System.out.println("No lo ha conseguido, lo sentimos");
                faltante=faltante-1;
                System.out.println("Le quedan "+faltante+" intentos");
            }
            else if (loteria>=2147483647) {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Tan grande no");
                break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Enhorabuena, tu ahora eres el campeón");
                System.out.println("Le ha tocado la lotería del gordo de navidad");
                System.out.println("Serán depositados "+loteria+" euros en su caja corriente");
                System.out.println("€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€€");
                puntuacion2=puntuacion1+2000000;
                System.out.println("Tiene una puntuación final de "+puntuacion2);
                break;

            }          
}  while ((faltante!=0) && (loteria<=3000000));      //repite el bucle mientras el contador no sea 0 y la lotería sea menor a 3M

        if (loteria<=3000000) {
        System.out.println("#################G A M E   O V E R   L O S E R#################");
        }
        else {
        System.out.println("Fin del juego");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Está pregunta necesita edición, indicas que el problema es con el Do-While, cuando en realidad no tiene nada que ver, por lo que el título no refleja el problema.

Comment: También revisa: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Lo que sucede @DaburaNet1998 que que el numero máximo que  soporta una variable `int es 2,147,483,647 que corresponde a 32bits` si ingresaras   `2,147,483,648` un valor superior obtendrías un error por lo tanto tu validación `if (loteria>=2147483647)` es incorrecta porque fallaría antes con el intento de captura del dato `newsc.nextInt();` ya que excede el numero máximo en memoria permitido, si necesitas numeraciones mas grandes puedes utilizar `long que soporta 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 al ser de 64bits`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema reside en `loteria=200000*numm2+1000+1000;` aquí al multiplicar 3000000*20000 te sales del rango de los enteros y en lugar de darte un error te da un número negativo.

Puedes probarlo haciendo un System.out.println(loteria); justo después de la asignación y veras que los valores son negativos.

Estas haciendo un overflow, una solución rápida sí necesitas tratar con estos números tan grande es usar long en lugar de int, y entonces el if que comprueba el rango entero positivo funcionará o al menos tendrá sentido. Ahora si asignas un valor mayor que el rango de int, lo que hace es saltar una Excepción

Otra cosa en lugar de poner directamente el rango, si necesitas usarlo para algo es mejor usar Integer.MAX_VALUE